# IE11 で table タグ内で template タグが使えない場合の代替手段

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer

vue.js を使用しているのですが、IE11 では table タグ内では template タグを使用できずに困っています。

```html
<tr>
  <td>hoge</td>
  <template v-for="item in items">
    <td>{{ item.fuga }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.piyo }}</td>
  </template>
</tr>
```

このようなことを IE でも実現する代替手段はあるでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

試していませんがこのような感じでいかがでしょうか。

```html
<tr>
  <td>hoge</td>
  <td v-for="v in items.reduce(function(a, c) { return a.concat([c.fuga, c.piyo]) }, [])">
    {{ v }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

理解しにくいのでcomputedにした方が良いかと思います。